# Conditional minimum of two columns with NA's

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, na, minimum

How can I efficiently create a new column which is the minimum of column 3 and column 2 when column 1 has a particular value?

Example:

```
my_dataframe=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1.0,2.0,3.0],
             'col2':[4.0,5.0,6.0],
             'col3':[0.25,np.nan,0.25]})

my_dataframe = my_dataframe.assign(col4 = lambda x: np.where(x['col1']>1, np.minimum(x['col2'], x['col3']), 0))
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in minimum
```

I assume that the `np.minimum`function can't handle the NA, so how can I work around this? The [numpy.nanmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html) function does not work as well.

It returns the following error, since it is not applied to an array
`TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

So I tried to write it as follows

```
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.assign(col4 = lambda x: np.where(x['col1']>1, np.nanmin(x['col2'].values(), x['col3'].values()), 0))
```

which returns the error:
`TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) with selecting both columns to subset by `[]` or similar with `np.nanmin`:

```
f = lambda x: np.where(x['col1']>1, x[['col2', 'col3']].min(axis=1), 0)
#another solution
#f = lambda x: np.where(x['col1']>1, np.nanmin(x[['col2', 'col3']].values,axis=1), 0)
my_dataframe = my_dataframe.assign(col4 = f)
print (my_dataframe)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   4.0  0.25  0.00
1   2.0   5.0   NaN  5.00
2   3.0   6.0  0.25  0.25
```

Comment: Of course, I tried `f = lambda x: np.where(x['col1']>1, (x['col2'], x['col3']).min(axis=1), 0)` which doesn't work obviously...

Comment: @Michael - yes, here is necessary working with 2d array or with `DataFrame`